# Reoreder factors for facet_wrap in a plot

Tags: r, tidyverse

I'm having the following problem. I have data from the package `gapminder` and I want to do a `geom_line()` plot of some countries, with gdpPercap and also the year. Here is my approach

```
country_europe <- gapminder %>%
  filter(continent == "Europe") %>%
  pull(country) %>%
  unique() %>%
  sample(8) %>%
  as.character()


gapminder %>%
  filter(country %in% country_europe) %>%
  mutate(country = reorder(country, desc(gdpPercap))) %>%
  filter(year > 1990) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = year, y = gdpPercap, color = country)) + 
  geom_point() + geom_line() + facet_wrap(~country) + 
  theme(legend.position = "None", axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

Here I'm triying to order the facets using `gdpPercap`, but this is not working because the gdp depends on the year.
[image]

For instance, in the Image Spain should be before Slovenia, because It has a bigger gdp for each year.
I tried calculating the mean of the gdp along the years, but it also didn't bring the desired result.
Any help with this approach?
Thanks

Edit: I think this is the best approach as suggested:

```
gapminder %>%
  filter(country %in% country_europe) %>%
  group_by(country) %>%
  mutate(gdp.mean = mean(gdpPercap)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  arrange(desc(gdp.mean)) %>%
  mutate(country=factor(country, levels=unique(country))) %>%
  filter(year > 1990) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = year, y = gdpPercap, color = country)) + 
  geom_point() + geom_line() + facet_wrap(~country)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could sort the countries based on the average `gdpPercap`, the maximum, or some other criterion and then set the factor order for `country` based on that. For example, using the average:

```
gapminder %>%
  filter(country %in% country_europe) %>%
  mutate(country = reorder(country, desc(gdpPercap))) %>%
  filter(year > 1990) %>%
  group_by(country) %>%
  mutate(avg.gdp = mean(gdpPercap, na.rm=TRUE)) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  arrange(avg.gdp) %>%
  mutate(country=factor(country, levels=unique(country)) %>%
  ggplot(... etc.
```

To address your comment: We want the countries to be ordered by their average (or maximum, or most recent, etc.) GDP per capita over the time period of the data. So we calculate that as a new column and then order the data by that column (`arrange(avg.gdp)` in this case).

The data frame is now ordered so that each country first appears in the data in the order of its average GDP per capita, which is the order we want for the facets. To set that as the order for `country`, we convert it to a factor and then use `unique(country)` to set the factor levels. This works because `unique` returns a vector that maintains the current order of the first appearance of a given value (for example, try running `unique(c(3,6,3,6,2,2,6))`).

Comment: Could you explain why using arrange before the mutate and the following line results on an ordered country?

Comment: Gocha, thanks for the explanation. So after the arrange I also could use mutate(country=fct_reorder(country, desc(gdp.mean))).

Comment: Yes, you can avoid the arrange step that way.